# Ember Template values backed from Controller instead of model from Route

Tags: ember.js

I have a template whose values are backed from the model in its corresponding Route.

But when i use the same name values in Controller, then the template values are updated from the Controller instead of values from Route.

My basic understanding is the template values are backed from the model hook from Route.

In my case the values are populated from the Controller. Am i missing something here or its the desired behaviour.

Link --> http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qufah/1/edit

Kindly comment the controller code so that the values are populated from the model.

Answer (score 1):

The default behaviour is for Ember to bind your template to controller properties. However, if your controller is an `ObjectController`, it will do something more clever: any property that is defined in your model, but **not** in your controller, will be inherited and available to your template!

For example,

```
App.PostRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return {title: "First Post", body: "Great job."};
  }
}); 

App.PostController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  title: "This post has been intercepted!"
});
```

with template:

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<p>{{body}}</p>
```

will show the intercepted title with the original blog post.

Edit: Here are the changes in [your JSBin](http://jsbin.com/hinabose/1/edit).